# How to properly use Alias in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Here is my code:

```
$this->db->select('course_name AS Course Name,course_desc AS Course Description,display_public AS Display Status',FALSE);
$this->db->from('courses');
$this->db->where('tennant_id',$tennant_id);
$this->db->order_by('course_name','ASC');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

and I got an error:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Name, course_desc AS Course Description, display_public AS Display Status FROM (' at line 1
```

and I got an error:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Name, course_desc AS Course Description, display_public AS Display Status FROM (' at line 1

SELECT course_name AS Course Name, 
       course_desc AS Course Description, 
       display_public AS Display Status 
FROM (`courses`) WHERE `tennant_id` = 'elicuarto@apploma.com' 
ORDER    BY `course_name` ASC

Filename: C:\wamp\www\coursebooking\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try

```
$this->db->select('course_name AS `Course Name`, course_desc AS `Course Description`, display_public AS `Display Status`', FALSE);
```

It's the space in your alias that is messing with you.

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure why you would want to, but I see nothing preventing you from writing

```
$this->db->select("course_name AS `{$variable}`", FALSE);
```

(showing just one field for simplicity)

**UPDATE 2**

Should be standard string conversion so I don't know why it doesn't work for you.. there's always split strings...

```
$this->db->select('course_name AS `' . $variable . '`', FALSE);
```

Comment: Another thing also, is it possible to put variable for the alias name instead?

Comment: It isn't working. It will just print the whatever variable name being put in the curly braces. Is there anything lacking?

Comment: Did you use double quotes (") for the string? Using single quotes (') will not allow for variable substitution.

Comment: Yes. I did exactly the same  as you but it's the variable name that is being printed.

Comment: Did you try split strings as per update 2? If that does not work either, I really have no clue