# How to add custom alias in select query codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to add custom alias in select query for codeigniter.

My code is :

```
   $this->db->select('id,Token, "M" as viral');
   $this->db->from('mytable');
   $mainUserQuery = $this->db->get();    
   $userData = $mainUserQuery->result_array();
```

How to assign custom alias in result?

Comment: What's `custom alias`?

Comment: Please share the current output and expected output.

Comment: i want to result [viral] = M

Comment: so what is the current output?

Comment: page error 500.

Comment: so what is the error ?

Comment: My page could not get any response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202867/discussion-between-dhaval-purohit-and-viral-patel).

Comment: Do not enclose `M` in quote marks. Your select should just be ` $this->db->select('id,Token, M as viral');`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly use Alias in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500500/how-to-properly-use-alias-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try:

```
$this->db->select('id,Token');
$this->db->select("'M' as viral", FALSE);
$this->db->from('mytable');
$mainUserQuery = $this->db->get();    
$userData = $mainUserQuery->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add alias using `as` in query like-

```
$this->db->select('m AS `viral`,id,token', FALSE)
```

Comment: don't you think this will give the error? all things should be in quotes right

Comment: @DhavalPurohit thanks for reminding :) i missed that

Comment: @ViralPatel surprisingly it works in my code. you can check below my query -    
                       `$query = $this->db->select("lm.*")
                      ->select("emp.emp_name as `employeeName`",FALSE)
                      ->from("$tb1 as lm")
                      ->join("$tb2 as emp","emp.emp_uid = 
                      lm.admissionIncharge","LEFT")
                      ->where("lm.leadId",$id)
                      ->get();
    $query = $query->result();  
    return $query;`  //you can check by removing FALSE also

Comment: i want to add custom alias which was not mention in table as a filed i want to just add my custom alais so i can check this user is valid or not ...

Comment: @ViralPatel I know what alias means and alias are not supposed to be the field names. I just showed my query which i used in my ci project ,i have given alias `employeeName` to `emp.emp_name`