# Can't access key of object because php CI assumes it's php syntax

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to get the key of my object to be returned to the controller but because the key contains `count` in it so the php assumes that it's php syntax while actually it's for the query sql `select count(nim)`.

This is my code, i will explain what this code do, the first 3 rows is i get the class id which class name is `$classname`. the second 3 rows is i count how many students (numbers of students) have the id of class that the value is `$classid` (this variable contains the previous id) then the last 3 rows is i get the room names which the capacity of the room is numbers of students (i mean so i could get the room names which that room capacity is as much as the number of students). Here's the problem, since the `$jumlah_siswa` (number of students) consists an object with the key `count(nim)`, when i try to access the key, the php assumes that `count()` is a php syntax while it's actually for my sql query.

What could i do so i can get the key which the key of the object is `count(nim)`

```
$this->db->select('kodeklas');
$id_kelas = $this->db->get_where('tik.kelas',array('namaklas'=>$data['namakelas']))->row();
$this->db->flush_cache();

$this->db->select('count(nim)');
$jumlah_siswa = $this->db->get_where('tik.mahasiswa',array('kelas_kodeklas'=>$id_kelas->kodeklas))->row();
$this->db->flush_cache();

$this->db->select('namaruang');
$opsi = $this->db->get_where('tik.ruangan',array('kapasitas'=>$jumlah_siswa->'count(nim)'))->result_array();
return $opsi;
```

Comment: Give it an alias

Comment: @JohnConde pardon me, i'm sorry. give it an alias does it mean like make a variable that holds the `$this->db->select('count(nim)');` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `alias` and then use it as an `object`([**reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500500/how-to-properly-use-alias-in-codeigniter)), like so -

```
$this->db->select('count(nim) as count_nim'); // now the count value will be stored in count_nim
// or $this->db->select('count(nim) count_nim');
$jumlah_siswa = $this->db->get_where('tik.mahasiswa',array('kelas_kodeklas'=>$id_kelas->kodeklas))->row();
$this->db->flush_cache();

$this->db->select('namaruang');
// use count_nim as an object ↓↓
$opsi = $this->db->get_where('tik.ruangan',array('kapasitas'=>$jumlah_siswa->count_nim))->result_array();
return $opsi;
```

See if this helps you.